# Displayed number deleted in array is not correct

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement

I have this program where it lets the user input an array of numbers.

For example, I would input an array size of 4 and input the numbers 40, 20, 1, and 8 as the elements in the array.

```
Input array size: 4
Input array elements: 40 20 1 8
```

The program also lets the user delete any elements from the array and the output should also show the element that was deleted.

For example, I would delete the number 40 from the elements. The output should be like this:

```
Enter the position of the element that you would like to delete: 1
The element 40 is completely deleted!
```

But instead of showing 40, the output goes like this:

```
Enter the position of the element that you would like to delete: 1
The element 20 is completely deleted!
```

Here is my source code:

```
    int a[100];
    int arraySize, elementPosition;

    printf("\n Input Array Size: ");
    scanf("%d", &arraySize);

    printf("\n Input Array Elements: ");
    for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d, ", &a[i]);
    }

    printf("\n Enter the position of the element you would like to delete: ");
    scanf("%d", &elementPosition);

    int deletedElement = a[elementPosition];

    if (elementPosition >= arraySize + 1)
    {
        printf("\n \n \t Invalid position! Enter numbers from 1 to %d only.\n", arraySize);
        getch();
        del();
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = elementPosition; i < arraySize - 1; i++)
        {
            a[i] = a[i+1];
        }
        printf("\n \The element %d is completely deleted!", deletedElement);
        arraySize = arraySize - 1;
        getch();
    }
```

It would be a very big help if someone can point out where did I go wrong.

Comment: Note that `40`is at position 0, not position 1.

Comment: An array begin at index 0. So when you do `deletedElement = a[elementPosition];` with elementPosition equal to 1, you get 20.

Comment: How is `a` declared, sure that `arraySize` elements can fit in it?

Answer (score 1):

Array index starts from `0`. This `deletedElement = a[elementPosition];` should be changed to `deletedElement = a[elementPosition - 1];`.

Additionally, you need to make sure that subtracting `1` does not cause `deletedElement` to become less than `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you test it, the index begin from 0 the position from 1.

```
int a[100];
    int arraySize, elementPosition;

    printf("\n Input Array Size: ");
    scanf("%d", &arraySize);

    printf("\n Input Array Elements: ");
    for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d, ", &a[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n Enter the position of the element you would like to delete: ");
    scanf("%d", &elementPosition);

    int deletedElement = a[elementPosition - 1 ];

    if (elementPosition >= arraySize)
    {
        printf("\n \n \t Invalid position! Enter numbers from 1 to %d only.\n", arraySize);
        getch();
        del();
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = elementPosition - 1; i < arraySize - 2; i++)
        {
            a[i] = a[i+1];
        }
        printf("\n \The element %d is completely deleted!", deletedElement);
        arraySize = arraySize - 1;
        getch();
    }
```